# When I change number of decimal places then value in the cell changes

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

For example I set 5.555 to the cell. When I change number of decimal places to 2, value changes to 5.56. If number of decimal places is 0, value in cell is 6.
If I add decimal places it does not change value.
Undo does not work too.

I have deleted all macros and all sheets, that were here before.

Comment: What is the question?  You have described expected behavior, called rounding.  The cell still contains the original value, if you set the format to display with enough decimals.

Comment: The value in the cell changes.

Comment: Problem was in option "Set precision as displayed" (File->Options->Advanced).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in option "Set precision as displayed" (File->Options->Advanced).

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/set-rounding-precision-HA010218870.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since your comments now mention a solution, this is an alternative, since what you are doing is expected by default.

Another way around this is to use truncate to shorten the value which effectively treats the value as a string which is what you're doing.

So, update the value of the cell from 5.555 to

```
=TRUNC(5.555, 2)
```

And it will update to 2 digits

Or, the formula can reference another cell. Some thing like

```
=TRUNC(a5, 4)
```

The idea of this is

```
=TRUNC(numberToChange , numberOfDigits)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But it was just option "set precision as displayed".